# `set_major_locator` removes x-ticks (and labels) from previous subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I ran into this strange problem with using `set_major_locator()`, when using subplots which have different x-axis limits. A minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime

h24 = mdates.HourLocator(interval=24)
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m %H:%M')

start1 = datetime(year=2016, month=7, day=7, hour=0)
end1   = datetime(year=2016, month=7, day=9, hour=0)

start2 = datetime(year=2016, month=9, day=30, hour=0)
end2   = datetime(year=2016, month=10, day=2, hour=0)

start3 = datetime(year=2016, month=5, day=8,  hour=0)
end3   = datetime(year=2016, month=5, day=10, hour=0)

pl.figure(figsize=(9,3))

ax=pl.subplot(131)
ax.set_xlim(start1, end1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(h24)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

ax=pl.subplot(132)
ax.set_xlim(start2, end2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(h24)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

ax=pl.subplot(133)
ax.set_xlim(start3, end3)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(h24)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

pl.tight_layout()
```

Which results in:

[image]

If I set the x-limit of all sub-plots the same (using in this case `ax.set_xlim(start1, end1)` for all sub-plots) it works as expected:

[image]

Also, leaving the different `set_xlim()`'s and removing the `set_major_locator()` and `set_major_formatter()` lines works (although I get unreadable x-labels in this case..):

[image]

Am I making a silly mistake somewhere, or are the missing x-ticks and labels in my first example a bug in Matplotlib?

*p.s. Matplotlib 3.0.2, Python 3.7.2*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of current versions of matplotlib you cannot reuse the same ticker and formatter for dates on several axes. So you need one locator and one formatter **per axes**.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime


def fmt_xaxes(ax):
    h24 = mdates.HourLocator(interval=24)
    fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m %H:%M')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(h24)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)


start1 = datetime(year=2016, month=7, day=7, hour=0)
end1   = datetime(year=2016, month=7, day=9, hour=0)

start2 = datetime(year=2016, month=9, day=30, hour=0)
end2   = datetime(year=2016, month=10, day=2, hour=0)

start3 = datetime(year=2016, month=5, day=8,  hour=0)
end3   = datetime(year=2016, month=5, day=10, hour=0)


fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(9,3))


ax1.set_xlim(start1, end1)
fmt_xaxes(ax1)

ax2.set_xlim(start2, end2)
fmt_xaxes(ax2)

ax3.set_xlim(start3, end3)
fmt_xaxes(ax3)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this covered anywhere in the documentation? I'm struggling to find any info in the documentation/examples/...?

Comment: No, that isn't shown anywhere. But there is a plan to change that behaviour anyways in one of the next versions.

Comment: See [#13482](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13482) vs. [#13439](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13439).

Comment: Interesting discussion... *"Probably not too many people are reusing locators anyway..."*. I definitely see a use for that: define once where and how you want your tick labels, and apply those settings to different axes. But SO is probably not the place to discuss this, and your answer provides a perfect solution to circumvent my issue.

Comment: Feel free to present your point of view in that linked thread. Such external views are important; often enough we simply do not know what users want and need to guess.